# ParallelStream for Files

Tags: java, java-8

The new Stream API in Java 8 is really nice, especially for the parallel processing capabilities.  However, I don't see how to apply the parallel processing outside of the Collections parallelStream method.

For example, if I am creating a Stream from a File, I use the following:

```
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("test.csv"));
```

However, there is no counterpart parallelStream method, like in Collections.  It seems like there could be one thread grabbing the next line, while there could be several threads parsing and processing the lines.

Could this be done with StreamSupport.stream()?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a much simpler answer: Any stream can be turned parallel by calling .parallel():

```
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("test.csv"))
                            .parallel();
```

The `.parallelStream()` method on Collection is just a convenience.

Note that, unless you're doing a lot of processing per line, the sequential nature of IO from the file will probably dominate and you may not get as much parallelism as you hope.

Comment: Thanks!  I am in fact doing a lot of processing per line, so this speeds it up significantly.

Comment: Just a little addition which stung me,  you need to make sure your code is in an auto closable to make sure that the file is closed.  http://www.rationaljava.com/2015/02/java-8-pitfall-beware-of-fileslines.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes - turns out you can create a parallel stream from the sequential stream with StreamSupport.stream().  Following the pattern of my question, it would look like the following.

```
StreamSupport.stream(Files.lines(Paths.get("test.csv")).spliterator(), true);
```

The 'true' is to make it parallel.  In testing, it expanded the use from a single core to all cores on my machine.  It read the lines in order, however the processing of the lines did not complete in order, which is fine for my purposes.